# How do I force Google Photos app to run without updates?

Tags: android

I recently updated my Nexus 4 phone to Android 5.1.1 10 days earlier. Today, I was checking my phone's photo/video storage with the built-in Google Photos app when it stopped working and demanded an update:

It only displays "Introducing the new Google Photos - all your photos in once place" with a "Get Update" button.

I updated the app and the update was complete rubbish. The latest version is 20x slower, taking half a minute to load all photos and videos instead of only loading the first few and then loading more as requested.

The Settings menu was also missing.

How do I get rid of the update prompt and just use the old version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the same position and have been working around it by accessing my photos via the camera app. Go into the camera app and swipe from the right edge to view your photos. Not nearly as good, but serviceable while looking for an alternative app. Forcing me to upload my photos to Google's servers is a deal breaking "feature" for me.